# Error in amcl node while configuring navigation stack simulation

Tags: slam, navigation, simulation, base-link, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have configured the navigation stack to a mobile robot model. When i tried to launch the below file got a following error. I am sure the error is with amcl node because i checked other nodes, launch file works fine without the amcl node.

```
<launch>
  <!-- Load the TortoiseBot URDF model into the parameter server -->
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find jmbot1_description)/urdf/jmbot1.1.urdf" />
  <!-- Start Gazebo with a world containing a large building-->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/willowgarage_world.launch"/>
  <!-- include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch"/ -->
  <!-- Spawn a TortoiseBot in Gazebo, taking the description from the
       parameter server -->
  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" 
    args="-param robot_description -urdf -model jmbot1.1 -x 8 -y -8" />
 
<!-- Convert /joint_states messages published by Gazebo to /tf messages,
       e.g., for rviz-->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher"
        type="robot_state_publisher"/>
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server"
        args="$(find mapping)/src/maps/willow.yaml"  />
  
<include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch"/>

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find jmbot1_description)/src/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find jmbot1_description)/src/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find jmbot1_description)/src/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find jmbot1_description)/src/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find jmbot1_description)/src/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>

 
</launch>
```

Error:

> [ERROR] [1454003234.548580927,
> 485.467000000]: Couldn't transform from hokuyo_link to base_link, even
> though the message notifier is in use

I have verified the rqt_graph and here is it for ref

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225324/error-in-amcl-node-while-configuring-navigation-stack-simulation/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2016-01-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm guessing you are using [this URDF from your other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/224754/error-while-building-map-in-slam_gmapping/).

Then, the solution is simple. You don't have a link which is called `base_link`, only one which is called `Base_plate`.
You need to configure the navigation (`move_base`, `amcl`, the different costmaps, etc.) to use you frame `Base_plate` (or change the link in your URDF).

Check out the Tutorials on the ROS wiki, especially [this one](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF) about how a usual setup for navigation is with regards to URDF and TF.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2